# Categories children in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: navigation, category

I am trying to put my categories and their children into a Bootstrap navbar. If category has Children it should become a dropdown link.

Here is the code:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('compositions') %}
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="workCategories">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   {% nav entry in categories %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
     {% ifchildren %}
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ entry.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       {% children %}
     </ul>
</li>
{% endifchildren %}
</li>
    {% endnav %}
  </ul>
```

It kind of work except that the top categories appear twice:

once with the dropdown and the children (which I want)
and once without the dropdown.

How could I nest those children without repeating them?

Comment: have you tried using {% else %} inside the if children ? 
The problem is, that if there are children you generate two <li>'s one without class="dropdown" and one with it

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would be easier to use a for-loop instead of that nav-loop in your case. Although it's harder to get multi-level-dropdowns

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('compositions') %}
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="workCategories">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    {% for entry in categories %}
      {% if not entry.hasDescendants() %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ entry.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            {% for child in entry.getDescendants() %}
              <a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all, this worked for me... not sure it's straight forward but it works...

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('compositions') %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#workCategories">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="workCategories">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  {% for entry in categories %}
  {% if entry.level == 1 and entry.children|length %}
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ entry.title }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        {% for child in entry.getDescendants() %}
          <li><a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
  {% elseif entry.level == 1 and not entry.hasDescendants() %}
    <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
</div><
</nav>
```

Comment: easier would be:  `{% set categories = craft.categories.group('compositions').level(1) %}` you wouldn't need the if level == 1 then